# Solspace Freeform Pro Captcha Error erases all form data

Tags: solspace-freeform, captcha

I'm using Freeform pro 4.1.3 and everything is working great with the default EE captcha, etc. However, when your captcha field is incorrect or not filled in, all of the data is lost on submit. This is a non-https page. Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I had my fields hard-coded instead of using {freeform:form} tag as mentioned here:

http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/17716/#63420

This solved the issue.